# what is logical AND doing here ,is it catching error

Tags: python, subprocess

If I run `script.py` without passing argument it shows

```
error: list index out of bounds
```

**script.py**:

```
from sys import *
if argv[1]=="what":
  print "done"
else:
  pass
```

If I run `script1.py` without passing errors it doesn't show error

**script1.py**:

```
from sys import *
if len(argv)==2 and argv[1]=="what":
  print "done"
else:
  pass
```

What is logical `AND` doing?

Comment: It's a compound if statement, `if a is true AND b is true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if len(argv)==2 and argv[1]=="what"
```

"Logical and" evaluate the left statement, then the right statement.

If the left statement return "false" then the right statement will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The and ensures that you have at least 2 arguments to the script as well as a second argument with value "what". If you don't pass in that argument, this evaluates to false by short-circuiting (since `len(argv)` is only 1), so there is no error.